# Need HTML UI for a local app to communicate with app backend

Tags: c#

I'm writing a C# program with a UI that needs to work with Mono (so WPF is out of the question). Between HTML5 and WinForms, HTML5 is much more suited to my needs, so I've decided to structure my app as a WebBrowser control that talks to a local backend. Currently this backend is a web server that serves the UI and executes commands from the frontend (File IO and other things JS cannot do). However, talking through a port on localhost doesn't sit well with me as it seems like there should be a more direct way without turning their machine into a web server even if I do block external requests. Does anyone know of a better way or is this just the trade off of using HTML/JS as the UI for a client app?

Comment: Awesomium costs $2,900 :)
It might not be pretty but I worked around the issue. I can poll the DOM elements of the WebBrowser control from the C# side, so I've created an invisible element that I populate with requests from JavaScript and another invisible element that I populate with responses from C#.